# Create procedure to evaluate an input parameter in mysql with regex

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to pass a parameter for a hex color to a procedure and evaluate to make sure it is a valid hex color.

This is the regex:

```
select '#008000' REGEXP '^#[0-9A-F]{6}$' as `ishexcolor`;
```

It needs to be inserted in this procedure:

```
BEGIN

INSERT INTO refdata.Color(`colorCode`, `notes`)
VALUES (_colorCode, _notes);

END$$
```

I am new to MySQL and not familiar with the syntax. 
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the solution:

```
BEGIN
    IF _colorCode REGEXP '^#[0-9A-F]{6}$' = 1 THEN
        INSERT INTO refdata.Color(ColorCode, notes)
        VALUES (_colorCode, _notes);
    END IF;
END
```